# ViewPager for matrix data

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to use a view flipper which works on a matrix and not a list which allowes me to either flip vertical or horizontal - but both at the same time. I know there are similar on lists working implementations like the [DirectionalViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager/) but they work on a list and the user has to configure if they want to flip horizontal or vertical exclusivly. I have a situation like in the image in mind:

[image]

The blue area is the current visible element. The grey boxes are the fragments the user can navigate to and from.